# dual quantum plane

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

Let $k\left\{\phi, \gamma\right\}$ be free algebra and $I_{q}$ be the two sided ideal generated by the elements $\phi \gamma + q^{-1}\gamma \phi$, $\gamma^{2}$ and $\phi^{2}$, $k_{q}[\phi,\gamma]= k\left\{\phi, \gamma\right\}/I_q$ is the dual quantum plane.

Any element $\phi$ and $\gamma$ incluiding in dual quantum plane  has 2x2 matrix reprensentations, how i can see them precisely?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $R:=k_q[\phi,\gamma]$. Since $R=k+k\phi+k\gamma+k\phi\gamma$, it is at most $4$-dimensional. Considering the left action of $R$ on itself, we obtain a faithful $4$-dimensional representation of $R$ given by
$\phi=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$
$\gamma=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&-q&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$
with
$\phi\gamma=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.
Now we see that $R$ is $4$-dimensional. Looking at the defining relations, we conclude that the two-sided ideals $I:=k\phi\gamma$ and $J:=k\phi+k\gamma+k\phi\gamma$ are unique minimal and maximal left ideals in $R$. We arrive at the description of all proper left ideals in $R$ : such an ideal is an arbitrary $k$-linear subspace $L\subset R$ in-between of $I$ and $J$, $I\subset L\subset J$. In particular, any $2$-dimensional cyclic (= one-generated) left $R$-module is isomorphic to $R/L$ with $I\subset L\subset J$ and $\dim_kL=2$. As a $2\times2$ matrix representation of $R$ is essentially a $2$-dimensional left $R$-module $M$, it remains to observe that a non-cyclic $M$ should have the form $M\cong k\oplus k$ (the trivial representation where $\phi$ and $\gamma$ are in the kernel). (I hope, it is easy now to write down explicitly $2\times2$ matrices of $\phi$ and $\gamma$ for every representation in question.)